# Can I retrieve the list of all items in an enumeration/type?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, types, enums, wrapper

I was wondering, is it possible to retrieve a list of all items in an enumeration?

For example I defined:

```
typedef enum YouJustUnlocked {
    Unlocked_A,
    Unlocked_B,
    //etc... many more
    Unlocked_Nothing,
}YouJustUnlocked;
```

Is there a way to retrieve the list of all "items" (inaccurate word) in the newly defined eumeration type YouJustUnlocked?

Is this supported by Objective-C?

I would like something like:

```
NSArray * array = [YouJustUnlocked returnAllItemsInWrapperObjectForm];
YouJustUnlocked item = (YouJustUnlocked) [array objectAtIndex:0];
//Assuming that array will contain some sort of wrapper object (like NSInteger)
```

Comment: NSInteger is not an object, you can't put it directly into an array.

Comment: I know, but that's why I am asking if there is a feature in the Objective C semantics that returns a generic wrapper (such as NSInteger) wrapping the enumeration I defined. Given the enumeration is defined by an int it would make sense. Also Objective-C and iOS uses the encoder funciton and there, to encode an enumeration, is common practice to use encodeAsInt function.. so I wonder if there is something similar.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. The question is quite clear if you read it.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible without using an equivalent list of descriptions:

YourClass.h:

```
typedef enum YouJustUnlocked {
    Unlocked_A,
    Unlocked_B,
    //etc... many more
    Unlocked_Nothing,
    // Add this:
    Num_Unlocked
}YouJustUnlocked;
```

YourClass.m:

```
static NSString *_youJustUnlockedDesc[Num_Unlocked] = {
    @"Unlocked_A",
    @"Unlocked_B",
    //etc... many more
    @"Unlocked_Nothing",
}

@implementation YourClass

+ (NSString *)youHaveUnlockedDesc:(YouJustUnlocked)yju {
    NSAssert(yju < Num_Unlocked, @"Out-of-range");
    return _youJustUnlockedDesc[yju];
}

...

@end
```

Notes:

- The `typedef` will be in the header file, while the description array will be within the implementation file.
- The `Unlocked_Nothing` should, conventionally, be the first element of the `enum`.

Comment: +1 Sneaky - though not exactly what the OP asked for, it works! Although it sounds like the OP is trying to do something that may be possible more elegantly if we knew what.

Comment: @Abizern Yeah, I probably missed something :)

Answer (score 0):

***IF*** the values of your enum are contiguous, you could perhaps do something like this:

```
typedef enum {
        eUnlockedNothing = 0,
        eUnlockedA, /* inferred that this is 1 */
        eUnlockedB,
        eUnlockedMax
    } YouJustUnlocked;

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = eUnlockedNothing + 1; i < eUnlockedMax; i++)
{
    [array addObject:@(eUnlockedNothing + i)];
}

YouJustUnlocked item = (YouJustUnlocked) [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]; //enums are default ints.
```

The result is that you have an array of your enum values that you can access by index. This array doesn't include the `eUnlockedNothing` or `eUnlockedMax` values.